# command not find in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.ats; do
  if [["$file" =~ _R079_]]; then
rm -f $file
  fi
done
```

It should be simple,delete all the files that contain *R079*

```
del.sh: line 4: [[263_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_4096H.ats: command not found
del.sh: line 4: [[263_V01_C00_R079_TEx_BL_4096H.ats: command not found
del.sh: line 4: [[263_V01_C01_R000_TEy_BL_4096H.ats: command not found
del.sh: line 4: [[263_V01_C01_R079_TEy_BL_4096H.ats: command not found
del.sh: line 4: [[263_V01_C02_R000_THx_BL_4096H.ats: command not found
del.sh: line 4: [[263_V01_C02_R079_THx_BL_4096H.ats: command not found
del.sh: line 4: [[263_V01_C02_R081_THx_BL_4096H.ats: command not found
del.sh: line 4: [[263_V01_C03_R000_THy_BL_4096H.ats: command not found
del.sh: line 4: [[263_V01_C03_R079_THy_BL_4096H.ats: command not found
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Add a space after the `[[` and again before the closing `]]`

Comment: `[[ $file =~ _R079_ ]]` Or `[[ $file == *_R079_* ]]` (spaces are required)

Comment: @anubhava 44 Yes,works now!

Comment: Suggest running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that there are no spaces after `[[` and before `]]` so you can use either:

```
[[ $file =~ _R079_ ]]
```

Or using glob:

```
[[ $file == *_R079_* ]]
```

However if you're just deleting files you need not use loop and can use:

```
rm *_R079_*.ats
```

Note that above `rm` command may give error if there are huge number of matching files. In that case use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*_R079_*.ats' -delete
```